# helm upgrade --install hanging

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to upgrade a release and install it in case it has not been installed previously, by using the following command:

```
helm upgrade --install --debug test-runtime .bob/test/test-0.0.1-ha27775e.tgz --namespace=default -f values.yaml --wait --timeout 900
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '41771'

[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:41771"

Release "test-runtime" does not exist. Installing it now.
[debug] CHART PATH: /home/test/test-0.0.1-ha27775e.tgz
```

But it is hanging.
The release has been installed but it seems that helm is waiting for something else.
All deployments are Ready, there is nothing that is blocking the upgrade.
The problem seems to be on my ingress (since I'am performing an upgrade the previous installation already has deployed this ingress, but the upgrade is changing the docker image deployed and not the ingress itself).

If I remove the ingress from the helm package it works.
So my question is: why am I facing this problem? 
The ingress seems to be deployed as well:

```
kubectl describe ingress test-ingress
Name:             test-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
TLS:
  testelglsv1secret terminates test.rose044.rnd.gic.example.se
Rules:
  Host                             Path  Backends
  ----                             ----  --------
  test.rose044.rnd.gic.example.se  
                                   /test   test-service:8080 (192.168.177.211:8080,192.168.52.175:8080)
Annotations:
  example.com/product-revision:                       R1B
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class:                         nginx
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret:         default/testtruststore
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client:  on
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth:   3
  example.com/product-name:                           test
  example.com/product-number:                         CXC 201 1390
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age    From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----   ----                      -------
  Normal  CREATE  2m32s  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/test-ingress
  Normal  CREATE  2m32s  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/test-ingress
```

To notice that this command has worked correctly until today, honestly I don't know what happened meantime.

here my helm version:

```
helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.2", GitCommit:"a8b13cc5ab6a7dbef0a58f5061bcc7c0c61598e7", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.15.1", GitCommit:"bf1a9adb587795da9a165ef411c3b6e1eeca6ffe", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Comment: Can you check if you have release named "test-runtime" already installed? Execute $ helm list -a

Comment: @MaggieO the release is not present, the same happens also when nothing is installed on the cluster.

Comment: Have you during helm setup created service account 
 for tiller and crb ? Have a look: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3133#issuecomment-356349192

Comment: I have restarted the cluster and the command hs started to work again.. maybe tiller’s problem? tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once I have restarted the K8s cluster the issue has disappeared.